# Trying to present basic DataFrame as Seaborn linear plot

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

I'd like to present my DataFrame as a Seaborn plot but can't make it happen. How to assign x and y variables correctly so that they represent columns and row values while rows will represent each line on the plot?

I know it is a pretty basic question but I'm just begging my Python adventure :)

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX5V4.png)
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bdrC.png)

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296334/create-seaborn-plot-with-pandas-of-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

For seaborn, in general, you need to get your dataframe in ["long-form" format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data).

Given your dataframe, there are many ways to get there. For instance:

```
df2 = df.unstack().reset_index()
df2.columns = ['year','area','value']
```

Then you can use that dataframe `df2` with seaborn:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df2, x='year',y='value',hue='area')
```